# Pros and Cons: Application level cache (Redis) vs Sidecar type cache (Polyscale.ai)

Tags: caching, redis, sidecar

Application level cache like Redis are very popular but does require developer to add and maintain the logic for caching (what to cache, when to invalidate etc) which might change over time.

Recently, came across [Polyscale](https://www.polyscale.ai/) cache, which adds a sidecar and seems like it automates the logic for caching along with many other benefits, seems too good to be true. Are there any downsides in practice for solutions like these? What could be the reasons these type of solutions are not as popular right now?

I tried reading their documentation, seems like main benefit is that it doesn't add to developer workload but couldn't find any benchmarks on performance (hit rate and latency)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.